# Wireless Stop Working After Kernel Updates 3.2.0-29-generic

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel

Two or three days back, I have updated to kernel `3.2.0-29-generic` from kernel `3.2.0-27-generic`. Now my wireless is not working since then...before it was working properly.

It keeps asking me the password. Sometime it connects but the speed the is very very slow ...like no more than 2 to 4kb.

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
04:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8185 IEEE 802.11a/b/g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 20)
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          12798  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23200  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             23441  0 
vboxdrv               282587  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
vesafb                 13844  1 
bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep
arc4                   12529  2 
rtl8180                40710  0 
mac80211              506816  1 rtl8180
eeprom_93cx6           12725  1 rtl8180
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224066  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  4 
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
cfg80211              205544  2 rtl8180,mac80211
psmouse                87692  0 
nvidia              12336440  41 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
w83627ehf              38805  0 
hwmon_vid              12827  1 w83627ehf
snd_seq                61896  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
serio_raw              13211  0 
parport_pc             32866  1 
snd                    78855  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
video                  19596  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
coretemp               13525  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
r8169                  62099  0
```

**lshw -C network**

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:27:0e:0e:8c:2b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.0.250 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:e3214000-e3214fff memory:e3210000-e3213fff memory:e3200000-e320ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL-8185 IEEE 802.11a/b/g Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 20
       serial: d8:5d:4c:ff:3e:ef
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8180 driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.251 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:16 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:e3100000-e31001ff
```

**UPDATE**

I have **Auto Login**. When I logout & login again, it **connects** & **works properly**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solved

> The problem is with Network Manager

```
gksu gedit /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Inside the file add the following for **WPA2**

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
        ssid="ESSID_IN_QUOTES"
        psk="ASCII PSK Password in Quotes"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=RSN WPA
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

> My Example : ssid="A-B-C-D"  & Password is  = psk="abc12345"

Then Remove **network-manager-gnome**

```
apt-get purge network-manager-gnome
```

> Setting the Wireless Interface to Connect at Boot

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following lines

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig wlan0 down
dhclient -r wlan0
iwconfig wlan0 essid "A-B-C-D"
iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
ifconfig wlan0 up
dhclient wlan0
```

Then restart networking .. I did a reboot

Note : I have already configured my router for **Static IP (Reserved IP from Router) &  DNS**

[For More Help ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188)